# ColdFusion FarCry CMS Installation Issue

Tags: coldfusion, content-management-system, cfml

We tried to install FarCry 7.2.11 on ColdFusion along with MSSQL version 2017 and we chose the FarCry bare bone, but got an issue at the final step of installation.

> An error occurred on executing the query

All the bare bone tables where already created. We couldn't find the issue and tried with Lucee server and we could make it to the Login page. But when we clicked login button an error occurred as follows.

[image: Screen Shot]

The FarCry folder was put in ROOT folder in C:/Lucee. 
Could anyone please get the actual FarCry installation doc or kindly provide us a better solution to solve the error.

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think this is the location of the installation docs - https://farcry.jira.com/wiki/spaces/FCDEV60/pages/12451884/FarCry+6.x+Installation  That is for version 6 but maybe it will help you. I also found this blog entry - https://www.dailyrazor.com/blog/installing-farcry-cms-on-lucee-server/  which does mention version 7.2